# ggplot2 incorrect median for a boxplot of identical values

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, median

Among many thousands of data sets my program occasionally encounters
those containing only identical values, for which I need ggplot2
to plot the same as base R does: simply plot the median at its correct
value.  Is there a way for ggplot2 to do this?

```
dput(df)

structure(list(station = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), value = c(1e-04, 
1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04
)), .Names = c("station", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

station value
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04
x   1.00E-04

# via base R:
boxplot(df$value ~ df$station,
main="base R:  correct median, \ncorrect data range")

# via ggplot2:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(df$station), df$value)) + 
geom_boxplot() +
ggtitle("ggplot2:  incorrect median, \nincorrect data range")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The median is correct in ggplot. Just 'zoom in' using `coord_cartesian` and have a look:

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(station), value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.00005, 0.00015))
```

Comment: Can ggplot2 zoom in automatically like base R does? The example is for a single box plot, but these water quality data often result in groups of flat box plots, which base R (from which I'm trying to move away into ggplot2) had no problem showing. I need ggplot2 to zoom in based on all groups and not show negative values on the y axis- which are impossible for this kind of data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how ggplot automatically calculates y-limits here, or how to modify these calculations. If you don't want negative values on the y-axis, you may set the lower ylim to 0.

Comment: Thank you, I tried using expand_limits(y=0) but it sets the line at the top of the plot. I took the range in your answer as a guide for percentage above and below y, and will use this for now: coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(a$value)-.5*min(a$value), max(a$value)+.5*max(a$value)))

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547448/r-for-the-same-code-labels-q1-median-appear-on-one-computer-but-dont-appea thanks